# How to manage react-native .env variables with PhpStorm Run/Debug Configuration?

Tags: react-native, environment-variables, phpstorm, webstorm, react-native-config

I am using PhpStorm and trying to automate the run with specific env variable. Managing .env variables for dev, staging, prod is very time saving and safe. So when I run `set ENVFILE=.env.staging && react-native run-android` from terminal, it picks the `.env.staging` variables but then I am not able to debug react-native app from PhpStorm. I am using react-native-config package.

When I run with this config it always picks from `.env` file.

[image: PhpStorm run/debug config]

Then I tried to run with package.json scripts like

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest",
    "android-dev": "set ENVFILE=.env.staging",
    "android-staging": "set ENVFILE=.env.staging && react-native run-android",
    "android-prod": "set ENVFILE=.env.prod && react-native run-android",
    "build-android-prod": "set ENVFILE=.env.prod && cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease && cd .."
  }
```

Although it opens the debug tab when I run debug with PhpStorm debug, but it was not showing debug variables.

So what I want is that clicking the Run/Debug choose the correct `.env` file and I will able to debug React Native app from PhpStorm.

Answer (score 1):

You can create separate run configurations with appropriate names  for `dev`, `staging` and `prod`, setting the corresponding environment variables (`ENVFILE=.env.staging`, `ENVFILE=.env.prod` and `ENVFILE=.env.dev`) in **Environmentvariables:** field of each of them, like:

[image]